# Can't have a separate depth and stencil buffer for a custom framebuffer? OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, rendering

I wanted to create a depth and stencil buffer for a new frame buffer object. But I got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED error. This is how I was creating the buffers:

```
GLuint depthBuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    GLuint stencilBuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &stencilBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilBuffer);
```

I couldn't get this to work so I ended up using a GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 texture format instead for both depth and stencil test like this:

```
GLuint depthStencil;
    glGenTextures(1, &depthStencil);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthStencil);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, depthStencil, 0);
```

But there should be a way to use seperate depth and stencil buffers, right? Please tell me how to do it :)
OpenGL Core 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API allows an implementation to support separate depth and stencil images in FBOs. That's (part of) why you can create and attach such images separately. The API does not *require* that any implementation supports this.

When the API gives you `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`, that means the implementation doesn't support what you asked the framebuffer to do. And if it doesn't support it, there's nothing you can do to *make* it support it.

OpenGL explicitly [requires support for combined depth/stencil images in FBOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Completeness_Rules). It does not require support for separate depth/stencil images in FBOs.